# How to prevent automatic video stretching? (Video Editor)

Tags: video-sequence-editor

working with the Blender video editor and importing files I took with a phone. Blender's automatically stretching them out to fill the screen, which I don't want. Is there any way to prevent this behavior automatically, rather than manually transforming each inputted video?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the video strip and choose the appropriate function from this dropdown menu.

[image]

You can find the same options while importing the strip, and Blender will remember your last choice.

[image]

Comment: I'm not seeing that "image" option (this is from when selecting a video strip). [What I'm seeing](https://imgur.com/a/r4gv5q5)

Comment: I'm in 3.1. In 2.93 was under Menu Strip > Image Transform. Anyway you get the options while adding  a new strip.